# Select template class constructors with different template parameters and causing compilation to fail

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor

Here is a minimal example, suppose that I have a vector class whose size can be either statically determined or dynamically determined. I allow different syntax for constructors like in the following example.

```
template<int RowAtCompileTime>
class Vector{
    //Other Details
    int rowNumber;
public:
    //For vectors with size known at compile time
    Vector(){
        static_assert(RowAtCompileTime > 0,"Cannot do this");
        rowNumber = RowAtCompileTime;
    }
    //For vectors with dynamic size
    Vector(const int _rowNumber){
        static_assert(RowAtCompileTime<=0, "Cannot do this");
        rowNumber=_rowNumber;
    }
};

template class Vector<0>;
template class Vector<1>;

int main(){
    //do nothing
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on the syntax, the goal is so-that only one of the constructor should be callable. Assume that the template parameter `RowAtCompileTime` is less than 0, which means it is dynamic, only the constructor `Vector(const int _rowNumber)` should be callable.

The code will not compile under g++-4.8 under std=c++11, which is expected, as the constructor will instantiate all the interfaces according to [this](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/162075-using-sfinae-constructors). It seems from the same website it is not possible to pass through this via SFINAE either (however, I am quite new to this concept, and I am not sure whether this is true). It is possible to offer partial template specializations, but if there many parameters like `RowAtCompileTime` the task seems very daunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae); which only works with function templates, so we need to make the constructors template:

```
//For vectors with size known at compile time
template <int V = RowAtCompileTime, typename = std::enable_if_t<(V > 0)>>
Vector() {
    rowNumber = V;
}
//For vectors with dynamic size
template <int V = RowAtCompileTime, typename = std::enable_if_t<(V <= 0)>>
Vector(const int _rowNumber) {
    rowNumber = _rowNumber;
}
```

then

```
Vector<0> v1(10);
Vector<1> v2;
```

BTW: `static_assert`s become meaningless for this implementation, they'll never be fired. But there's always only one constructor being callable, depends on the template argument. Call to improper constructor would cause compilation fail.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qVdSrlr8lFeTkNTU)

Comment: Thank you very much for your timely reply. I wonder whether you will be so kind to explain why I need the additional template parameter 'template<int T = ...>'? Thank you very much

Comment: @RanWang Because SFINAE only works with function templates, so we have to make constructors template and introduce template parameters; and you want to select constructor base on the template parameter `RowAtCompileTime`, so we introduce a new template parameter `V` with default value as `RowAtCompileTime`.